# The correct way of displaying data on the iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I 'm developing an application for the iPhone and i'm unsure on what methods to use to display the information. I have a database that contains information of subjects (e.g., Subject : Maths, Day:Monday, Time:2-3, Teacher : Jim).

Each day in dynamic, meaning it can either be anything between 5-8 subjects in total for any given day. On the iPhone i want to display the following information ..

```
Lesson : 
Time : 
Teacher : 
Addition Notes :
```

Lets say that i want to display the fields above in the same style, how can i make something dynamic that the user can scroll though to view everything needed? (my approach was to create a lot of labels and link each one however this isnt the way to go ...)

Answer (score 4):

You could use UITableView filled up with UITableViewCells. Every cell displays a day. After clicking on the day, you could go to a next UITableView with every cell containing the subject info.

Answer (score 2):

As it seems necessary, have you read the [human interface guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Introduction/Introduction.html)? They describe all the best practices for various purposes, mainly showing data.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two ways you could approach this... first would be to create a main navigation table view and then the user can choose which day they would like to view and that view would display all the information that you show (Lesson, Time, etc.) I think this is what the above poster is saying.

Or another way you could do it would be display one page with a UIPickerView and have them pick a day from that and then the information would refresh.

You'd just have the PickerView and would display

```
Lesson: <Label linked to lession variable>
Time: <Label linked to time variable>
Teacher: <Label linked to teacher variable>
Additional Notes: <Label linked to additionalNotes variable>
```